# Selenium - How to test video

Tags: testing, selenium

My requirement is to test video played on particular web page. I need to capture its screen at particular interval. Its start time, end time, duration etc.  How to do that

Answer (score 0):

The application I test also has video requirements. Rather then trying to get Selenium to do something it really isn't made for, I created my own methods that parse the URL of the video and make sure it gets a 200 HTML response, just to make sure there's a video there.

Otherwise, I don't believe there are any ways to get the duration of the video without relying on what's in the markup. If you do use what's there, the Java API allows you to take a screenshot as follows:

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

Comment: Hi,

My problem is not screenshot, I am able to take screenshot at regular interval. The problem I am facing is If I am taking screenshot after page load & after few seconds. But the problem is all screenshot look same.

I am using python, but worked in java. Can u share code snippet?